# Code Stucks at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am trying to download a file using ServeRelativeUrl  by OpenBinaryDirect Method and it works fine. But often,  irrespective of size, extension or any other file metadata it just get stucks.

Please see the code below, it gets stucks at either of the bolded lines (more often at ExecuteQuery()) and throws an operation timeout error, later I tried to give timeouts (shown in italic) but then it got stuck for infinite time until the main thread got killed.

```
clientContext.RequestTimeout = -1;
FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Create))
{

                    fileInfo.Stream.WriteTimeout = -1;

                    fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
fileInfo.Stream.Dispose();
```

size of the file in explorer remains 0kb.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKWau.png

Comment: Can your code read the stream from file.ServerRelativeUrl? Test it by reading `fileInfo` in a `Stream s` variable first. (I can't see what is bolded or what is italic, please edits.)

Comment: yes code is able to read the stream from ServerRelativeUrl.

Answer (score 1):

I maybe had a similar problem: I got a timeout problem after downloading a lot of files, I solved this by disposing the "fileInfo" object by putting it into a using statement:

```
using (var fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(_context, relativeUrl))
{
    if (Directory.Exists(targetDirectory))
    {
        targetDirectory = Path.Combine(targetDirectory,
            Path.GetFileName(new Uri(relativeUrl).LocalPath));
    }

    using (Stream destination = System.IO.File.Create(targetDirectory))
    {
        for (var a = fileInfo.Stream.ReadByte(); a != -1; a = fileInfo.Stream.ReadByte())
            destination.WriteByte((byte)a);
    }
}
```

After that it worked. It seems if the object is not disposed you run into a connection limit.

Answer (score 0):

I just migrated ~100 files from OnPrem to SPO using the same method.
Some difference from my solution:

> clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

is only required to ensure file.ServerRelativeUrl is initialized, so you can remove it from this position and load it before.

As I had to download+upload multiple dependend files, I copied each SP binary stream into MemoryStreams with Async methods and disposed the SP streams as fast as possible. I think there will be a connection limit.

I disposed the fileInfo itself instead of the inner Stream object.